# Windows 8.1 Not detecting Realtek wireless network card

Tags: windows, windows-8, wireless-networking

Not sure if this is the place to ask but i've asked on a few other sites and haven't really got a solution for it.

I just recently installed Windows 8.1 today and am having problems using my wireless card to connect to the internet. If I plug an ethernet cable in it works fine but its not giving me any options for connecting wirelessly.

I've downloaded the drivers multiple times but I can't seem to get wireless working, only wired.

My driver version is RTL 8168.

I know this card supports wireless because it worked completely fine under linux.

Comment: When you say that network card works fine under linux but still windows 8.1 unable to find the wireless network, It reveals that the problem could be with wireless driver. Uninstall and reinstall your wireless driver or update the driver.

Comment: I have also added few more steps in the answer box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below steps and check your outcome. Hope this should help you.

1. Right click on the Network adapter and try 'Disable' and 'Enable'
2. Right click on the Network adapter and try Disconnect and Connect
3. Go to Start > Computer > right click > Manage > on the right pane, select the Network adapter > right click and choose 'Uninstall'. Once the Uninstall finished, click on Search for New hardware changes. This will install the wireless adapter again or install the latest driver downloaded from the vendor's site
4. Right click on the Network adapter > Properties > select "Internet Protocol version 4(TCP/IP) > Properties > click on "Obtain IP address Automatically" > click on OK.

Comment: I have tried this yet it still shows no wireless connections and the driver is still only a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller. It's as if its only installing an ethernet driver with no support for wireless even though I have a WiFi card

Comment: Turns out I had an unknown device in device manager which was the wireless LAN Realtek driver